# SQL SMO: Find default constraints dependent on function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

The script below alters the function [dbo].[RetrieveDefaultValueForColumn1]. However, since this function is used as default values for Column1 in two tables (Table 1 and Table 2), these default constraints have to be temporarily dropped and re-added. Like this:

```
-- drop dependent default constraints
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Table1_Column1];
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Table2_Column1];
GO

-- alter function
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RetrieveDefaultValueForColumn1] ()
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 1
END
GO

-- re-add dependent default constraints
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Table1_Column1] DEFAULT ([dbo].[RetrieveDefaultValueForColumn1]()) FOR [Column1];
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Table2_Column1] DEFAULT ([dbo].[RetrieveDefaultValueForColumn1]()) FOR [Column1];
GO
```

If I were to programatically generate this script using SQL SMO "scripting/dependency discovery" functionality, **how do I identify all default constraints dependent on the function?**

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough. Here you go, powershell style. Note that I'm not being careful about the files already existing. Run this in a test environment first to make sure you don't break anything; it worked for me but that doesn't mean it'll work for you. At any rate, this script will output two SQL scripts; one to drop the constraints and one to create them.

```
import-module sqlps;
$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$db = $s.databases[ 'adventureworks2012' ];

$drop_options = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions;
$create_options = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions;

$drop_options.filename = 'c:\temp\default_drops.sql';
$drop_options.tofileonly = $true;
$drop_options.scriptdrops = $true;
$drop_options.AppendToFile = $true;

$create_options.filename = 'c:\temp\default_creates.sql';
$create_options.tofileonly = $true;
$create_options.scriptdrops = $false;
$create_options.AppendToFile = $true;

foreach ( $table in $db.tables ) {
    foreach ( $column in $table.columns ) {
        if ( $column.defaultconstraint.Text -eq '(getdate())' ) {
            $column.defaultconstraint.script( $drop_options );
            $column.defaultconstraint.script( $create_options );
            $column | select parent, name, defaultConstraint;

        }
    }
}
```